# PHP Call to undefined function twitter oauth 1.1

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-oauth

I am trying to scrape my Twitter Feeds with PHP and am receiving the following error:

```
$my_tweets = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => 'TrulyDesigns', 'count' => 1));

echo '<div class="twitter-bubble">';
if(isset($my_tweets->errors))
{           
echo 'Error :'. $my_tweets->errors[0]->code. ' - '. $my_tweets->errors[0]->message;
}else{
echo makeClickableLinks($my_tweets[0]->text);
}
echo '</div>';

//function to convert text url into links.
function makeClickableLinks($s) {
return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a target="blank" rel="nofollow" href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);
}
```

Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function makeClickableLinks()

Comment: Try to access that function using `$this->`.

Comment: @Nitin Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'makeClickableLinks' (T_STRING)

Comment: Other option is declare your makeClickableLinks() above the if condition. It may work

Answer (score 0):

Define the function `makeClickableLinks` at the top; you are calling it before you are defining it.

```
//function to convert text url into links.
function makeClickableLinks($s) {
  return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a target="blank" rel="nofollow" href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);
}

$my_tweets = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => 'TrulyDesigns', 'count' => 1));

echo '<div class="twitter-bubble">';
if (isset($my_tweets->errors)) {           
  echo 'Error :'. $my_tweets->errors[0]->code. ' - '. $my_tweets->errors[0]->message;
} else {
  echo makeClickableLinks($my_tweets[0]->text);
}
echo '</div>';
```